# Use Empty Function with Foreach loop

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

I want to output a message when there are no items in the database. The
code does not print the statement when the database doesn't have data.

```
This is my code,
<?php foreach($latest_tenders as $tenders):
if(!empty($tenders)){ 
$time = strtotime($tenders['post_date']);
                      $month=date('m', $time);
                                switch($month){
                                   case 1:
                                    echo "January "; break;
                                      .
                                      .
                                      .
                                    case 12:
                                     echo "December "; break;
                                   default:
                                    echo "January ";
                            }
echo date('d', $time).', ';
echo date('Y', $time).'&nbsp';
echo date('h', $time).':'; echo date('i',     $time).' |&nbsp';?>
     <i class="fas fa-user"></i> <?php echo $tenders['author'];?></p> 
       </div><br/>
     <?php 
         }
            else{?>
      <p style=" font-size:13px; word-spacing: 5px;color:tomato;">
          Tender Name: No advertised Tenders, Check again later.
      </p>
        <?php
            }
            endforeach;
            ?>
```

Comment: Please show more code: what is in the `if` and in the opening part of the `foreach`?

Comment: Please, properly format your source code. It's currently hard to read.

Comment: In addition, what do you mean by *'...when there are no items in the database.'*?

Comment: When you say *'The code does not print the statement when the database doesn't have data.'*, Which statement are you referring to?

Comment: The else statement

Comment: The code is supposed to output the else statement when there is no advertised tenders in the database.

Comment: Without knowing the structure of the variable `$latest_tenders`, it's hard to know how your logic behaves.

Comment: Please [visit the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take a tour to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Do some research, and search for related topics on Stackoverflow; if you get stuck, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `$latest_tenders` is your database result, first check if the `$latest_tenders` array is not empty. If it's not empty: loop over `$latest_tenders` and print its `$tenders`. Else (it is empty): print your error message.

```
<?php if(!empty($latest_tenders)) : ?>
    <?php foreach($latest_tenders as $tenders):
        $time = strtotime($tenders['post_date']);
        $month=date('m', $time);
        switch($month){
            case 1:
                echo "January "; break;
                    .
                    .
                    .
            default:
                echo "January ";
        }
        echo date('d', $time).', ';
        echo date('Y', $time).'&nbsp';
        echo date('h', $time).':';
        echo date('i',     $time).' |&nbsp';
    ?>
        <i class="fas fa-user"></i> <?php echo $tenders['author'];?></p></div><br/>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php else : ?>
    <p style=" font-size:13px; word-spacing: 5px;color:tomato;">
        Tender Name : No advertised Tenders for No, Check again later.
    </p>
<?php endif; ?>
```